# Inline small jss css

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

GTmetrix advises I inline these

```
<action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
```

I inlined them to the footer removed the calls in the `page.xml` and awesome got a A on pagespeed

However I have a webpos extension and it doesn't use the template header or footer so checkout doesn't work unless I replace the call outs in `page.xml`

So my question is how do i inline these  do i do it in the extensions phtml?

Answer (score 0):

It is always good to keep them where they belongs that's `page.xml` but if placing it somewhere else is making your performance better then alright.
You've to define them in `xml` file of that extension probably in default section of ut.Have you checked this after merging too ?  because these JS order can mess things around when you merge them all.